# Is it possible to configure an nginx location to serve a root folder based date of creation?

Tags: nginx

I have a set of static files that are automatically deployed into a currently configured nginx root location.

Each build effectively generates a versioned set of resources (static html/css/javascript) as per the below:

```
location ~ ^/(mylocation) {
        root    /local/0/www/;
        autoindex on;
        auth_request off;
        expires 5d;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        proxy_cache            static_one;
        proxy_cache_valid      200      60m;
        proxy_cache_valid      404      1m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
```

Inside the "mylocation" directory are a number of versioned directories 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2 etc.

Is it feasible to have nginx serve the most recent (highest version number) as the default whilst still enabling it to serve the individual versions directly?

Comment: Id say create a shell script or something that symlinks the latest folder to a folder called latest for example and let nginx look there, don't bother nginx to do the math, it wasn't built for that.

Comment: I did think it might be asking a bit much of nginx. Shell script it is then. Thanks